# Minimizing a fraction with probability

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, optimization

Let $V \sim Uniform(0, a)$, and let $c_f, c_r$ be constants.

I need help finding the value of $T$ that minimizes the fraction

$$\frac{c_fP(V\leq T) + c_r P(V > T)}{\int_{0}^{T} P(V > x) \mathop{dx}} $$

---

I computed:

$$P(V\leq T) = \int_0^T \frac{1}{a} \mathop{dz} = T/a. $$

Also $P(V > T) = 1 - T/a$.

Then, I got

$$\int_0^T P(V > x) dx = T - T^2/2a. $$

Plugging it in, I get:

$$\frac{c_f (T/a)+c_r(1 - T/a)}{(T - T^2/2a)},$$

which I am supposed to minimize, if my other calculations are right. I need to find the value of $T$ that minimizes this. But I got $T \to \infty$ when I tried it. But I think this is wrong. I think it should be finite.

T > 0 by the way. It is time.

Comment: Your computation is valid only when $T<a$. For $T>a$ do a separate computation . You will get $\frac {c_f} {a(1-x^{2}/2}$  for all $T>a$. Now minimize over $T\in [0,a]$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Did you mean $T$ instead of $X$? Even so, I am still struggling. Should I get only one value of T? Or is my computation right for $T<a$ and I just need the second value of $T$.

Comment: Your computation is fine for $T<a$. Find minimum value for $0\leq T \leq a$. You will also have to compare the minimum value with the constant value on $[a,\infty)$ to see which is smaller.

Comment: Do I need to even bother for $T > a$ because it's a probability distribution $U(0, a)$

Comment: You are asked to minimize over all $T$, so you cannot restrict attention to $T<a$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't think the value for $T > a$ has a min

Comment: I got $T = \pm \sqrt{2}$ for $T > a$ and $T = 2a$ for $T < a$.  Is this right? But all of these critical points give me $\infty$, so how do I pick the minimum one? I found it by taking derivatives

Answer (score 1):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=critical+points+%28b*x%2Fa+%2B+c*%281+-+x%2Fa%29%29%2F%28x+-+x%5E2%2F%282*a%29%29

Comment: I don't think that is a minimum

Comment: i've plotted a graph of this function. Under certain conditions on $c_f$ and $c_r$ it is a minimum